# Amazon RDS free tier instance disappeared suddenly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a Free Tier t3.micro RDS instance in a totally fresh AWS account. Today when I logged into my AWS root account to check something. My DB instance is just not showing up in the list. But I'm able to connect to the database using Azure Data Studio and query it like before. What is going on?
[image]
[image]

I can see that I've only consumed 48% of the Free tier limit. What is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you selected correct region. It should correspond the one you created resources in. [image]